# Should I get another dog to keep my dog company?

Tags: dogs, exercise

Just wanted to get some input and feedback about getting another dog to keep my dog company at home while I'm at work.

I have a small Dog - high energy, and wonderful. I walk him twice a day and play with him. Often he's bored and just sits and stares at me at home, and I feel bad. He has me to engage him, and roommates but that is it. He's super smart, and very well behaved. He powers through his kong wobbler toy in 10 mins or less, and puzzle toys don't keep him occupied for long.

I'd be interested in feedback on your experience with my concerns about another dog below:

- Is it a lot more work? (walking 2 dogs vs. 1), other scenarios, etc..
- Have you experienced more "hands-off" time w/ your dogs after getting a second? (play w/ each other, opposed to 20-30 mins time spent dedicated play time with one dog) - less time staring at you, maybe doesn't need as many walks? etc..
- Does getting another dog really make them both happier? What about longevity, health, obedience, etc..?

What other input or experiences have you had? Harder to get dog-sitters?

Personally I'm suffering from a bit of guilt around my dog not liking to be home alone.  I think being a good dog owner involves making the dog's life the best you can within reason - part of why I'm considering a second bundle o' joy for the house.

Thank you for all of your sage input.

Comment: Well they are pack animals and although you are part of his pack another dog to keep him company and have someone to play with would probably be a good thing. Whether or not it works for you is really up to you to decide. I'd probably want to make sure a new companion is at a comparable energy level.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a small Schnoodle (25 lbs) - high energy, and wonderful. I walk
>   him twice a day (~1hr 15 mins total) and play with him. Often he's
>   bored and just sits and stares at me at home, and I feel bad. He has
>   me to engage him, and my two roommates when they are home but that is
>   it. He's super smart, and very well behaved (I trained him well and
>   got all the bad behaviors out for the most part). He powers through
>   his kong wobbler toy in 10 mins or less, and puzzle toys don't keep
>   him occupied for long.

Honest answer, he is bored. He's looking to you because he wants engagement from you. Play is good but he needs more. What are your walks like? If he is still not tired after 1.25 hours of walking a day then he isn't doing enough during that walk. Do things like agility and obedience which mentally and physically tire dogs out. This is great for him because he wont be bored and sleep in the day. An hours casual walk/stroll is different to an hours walk filled with activity.

I have two GSDs and having 2 dogs is incredibly hard work at times. We walk them separately for 2 reasons;

1. Because if they are walking together (especially if theyre young) pack mentality sets in and they start looking to each other for engagement and ignore you, they become less obedient and harder to control.

   2. Its hard to mentally and physically exercise 2 dogs at the same time, they get in each others way, they play with each other rather than listen to me and if a fight breaks out with them or another dog its just me, and its hard to separate alone.

Naturally when you have 2 dogs you need to divide your time equally, they can get jealous, but it just happens naturally. We tend to crate one and give the other some sole attention and brush them, do some obedience and let them have food separately and then swap over.

We had one dog and then we got another and dynamics changed quickly. The older one grew up quicker and started being more dominating to the other, making sure the other knew she was top dog in the pack. The newer one tried her luck occasionally and stood up to her but quickly got put back down, as she got older she got more independent, stronger, bigger, mature and started to stand up to the older one which is how more severe fights started to happen. They needed time to establish pack hierarchy. We stopped this as much as we could but its natural for dogs to do this. They're fine now, no fights in a long time but thats because the order has been settled. This is something to bear in mind if you get another, dynamics.

Another thing to consider is gender. If you get another boy then chances are there might be some fights/scraps for top dog. If you get a female then you have the issue of her going into heat and they will need separating until she is out of it. Unless one or both have, quite frankly, unnecessary surgery to quash that.

In the day while we're at work, we separate them, to give them some time alone and then when we're back they can play etc under close supervision incase something happens. Some times play can go too far, one gets hurt - accidents happen, one might not take the hint from the other etc, we need to be there to manage dynamics.

If you where to get another dog you would need to be there for every bit of contact and interaction they have for a while to make sure they get on etc. If you separate them in the day then it renders what you're looking for (a companion) pointless. We got another dog because we wanted one, not for company for the other.

Naturally when you get a dog you spend more time with them and not going out as much, thats just part of having a dog.

If Im honest for now id just engage with him more. If hes bored he wants to do things with you. He is crossed with a poodle which are incredibly smart and intelligent workers. So do things like obedience, agility, take him to dog classes, more challenging toys, challenging puzzles, look at getting a flirt pole. Improve your walks, make them action packed and not just a light stroll throwing a ball occasionally and playing with a fellow walkers dog.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thats fine but engage with him too, dont let him do his own thing make you the centre of his attention this is done through play and obedience.

Comment: Having company often works. It has worked for my dogs. However, I would recommend that you have dogs the same sex. With mixed sexes many times the the female will try and dominate no matter what size the male is. With the same sex dogs you will have some issues until dominance is established.Once done that issue goes away. The male - female issue usually continues as males constantly piss off the female. And you don't know the reason for it, neither does he.